# I'm trying to get an X-Auth-Token using the FIWARE token_script.sh file but it gives me an empty token

Tags: fiware

I use my FIWARE Lab account credentials (username and password) but an empty Token is returned to me. What I see in the output is: "Token: ", so I can't get an X-Auth_Token for a specific IOTA service.

Is that a FIWARE temporary problem?

Comment: please elaborate your question. what you do mean be FIWARE account credentials, it is FIWARE lab credentials?

Comment: oh, you are right. yes, I mean the FIWARE lab credentials.

Comment: Could you check it again, I do not see any problem. Additionally, could you give me details of that tocker_script.sh that you are using?

Comment: I tried again but again an empty token is returned to me.
The token_script.sh I am using is:

#!/bin/bash

echo ""
read -p "Username: " USER
read -s -p "Password: " PASSWORD
echo ""

RESP=`curl -s -d "{\"username\": \"$USER\", \"password\":\"$PASSWORD\"}" -H "Content-type: application/json" https://orion.lab.fiware.org/token`

TOKEN=`echo $RESP`
echo -e "\nToken: $TOKEN"
echo ""

Comment: To be exact, I'm running these two commands:
# wget --no-check-certificate https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fgalan/oauth2-example-orion-client/master/token_script.sh
# bash token_script.sh

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this script is obsolete. If you take a look into the [Official Documentation](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/quick_start_guide/index.html) of Orion Context Broker, you can find the corresponding scripts that you should use ([token_script.sh](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/FIWARE-Ops/Tools/master/GetToken/get_token.sh)). Keep in mind that you have to provide the corresponding project (orion-gi) apart from the user and password.